# CSS is background-mode-blend not a thing yet?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get that property to work so I don't have to resort to photoshop to utilize effects like screen and multiply and stuff. I see references to it everywhere, but I can't seem to get it to work on a page I'm working on.

Maybe I'm implementing it wrong?

```
.nav-items {
display: inline-block;
font-family: Porter;
font-size: 2em;
letter-spacing: .05em;
margin: .3em;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #1e1e1e;
background-blend-mode: screen; }
```

of which nav-items is li's in a particular ul. Background is just a solid gray block not using the screen blend mode. Any wisdom to be shed?

Comment: Tried both Chrome and FF

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode):

> Blending modes should be defined in the same order as the `background-image` CSS property

But you are not specifying a `background-image`. `background-blend-mode` does not blend colors, it blends images.

Comment: So wait, why wouldn't something like this work then:

body {
    background-image: url("../assets/images/bgart.jpg");
    background-blend-mode: screen; }

Comment: Put up a sample. What do you expect to happen? How can you blend only one thing?

Comment: Well, I suppose what I'm trying to do might not be even possible, but I have my page set to have a single image as the background, and I would like the background colors of any other elements (i.e. li's in this case) to have a blend mode with it. Here is a snippet of the effect I'm looking for (which I used PS to create, as I can't get it to work with CSS): https://puu.sh/kHcmu/e5b8148c89.jpg The lighter areas are screen-blended layers of #1e1e1e. I'd like those to be blended background-color's of elements in the html.

Comment: Essentially adding opacity, but keeping intensity in a way instead of just getting darker and harder to see.

Comment: Any chance you are looking for something like this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/

Comment: I'm not using background images, so I don't think that applies, I'm just using the background-color of an element.

Comment: Right now, after lots of experimentation, I'm having a hard time spotting the difference between 'Screen-blended #1e1e1e' and 'Opacity: 0.1 #C0C0C0'

So, I may just opt for some rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.1); at this point which seems to get the effect I want.

Answer (score 0):

Blend modes can be used in 2 different attributes,

- background-blend-mode
- mix-blend-mode

The first one sets the effect between 2 backgrounds in the same element (it can be an image and a solid color)

The second one sets the effect between the element and the underlying elements (that seems to be your case). But note that it will affect all the element, (borders, text, and so on) - not only the background